# Is there a better way to get several identical copies of a list in Python?

Tags: python, copy

I am writing a program that simulates 2D differential equations. In one function I need to save the last two iterations in the variables `y_nm1` and `y_n`, as well as the next iteration in `y_np1`. They are initialized to `y0`, the initial value of the differential equation. Since `y0` is a list (because 2D differential equation), they need to be copied to avoid being linked. I'm currently achieving this with the following code:

```
from copy import copy

y_nm1, y_n, y_np1 = copy(y0), copy(y0), copy(y0)
```

This is ugly. Is there a better one-liner I can use that I'm not aware of?

Comment: Are the iterations' calculation done in place? If not, "copies" would be naturally made by virtue of just keeping around references to the earlier iteration data.

Comment: Since `copy(y0)` is shallow I would probably use `y0[::]`  or `list(y0)`. Though I almost never assign to multiple variables on one line unless explicitly unpacking.

Comment: don't use the `copy` module, just use `y0.copy()` etc, but aside from that, this seems like a perfectly reasonable and readable way to accomplish what you want. What exactly do you mean by "better", here?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list using `for` loop:

```py
from copy import copy

y_nm1, y_n, y_np1 = [copy(y0) for _ in range(3)]
```